# How do I kill gnome-settings-daemon?

Tags: gnome-settings-daemon

I'm trying to kill gnome-settings-daemon as mentioned at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting so that I can examine keyboard events with xev. However, when I do

```
killall gnome-settings-daemon
```

gnome-session just restarts it again.

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Sorry, I had put the wrong url in. Now corrected. I'm trying to track down a keycode for a laptop key, and the updated url says to kill gnome-settings-daemon first in case it is eating some events. That's a topic for a whole new question though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

11.10...

```
sudo -e /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop
```

Change `X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true` to `X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false`

Save. Does log out/log in suffice? Not sure. Maybe just reboot for simplicity.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick, thanks. I just had to log out and back in again.