# Prevent unity-settings-daemon from restarting in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, gnome-settings-daemon

I'm trying to restart unity-settings-daemon with the     --debug flag. I couldn't find any information on unity-settings-daemon.

I tried the process listed for 11.10 here: [How do I kill gnome-settings-daemon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93578/how-do-i-kill-gnome-settings-daemon). I was able to get that process to work for me on Fedora 20.

I changed

```
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true to X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false
```

in

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/unity-settings-daemon.desktop
```

Then after reboot,

```
killall unity-settings-daemon
unity-settings-daemon --debug
```

I get the error:

```
(unity-settings-daemon:2390): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down
```

If I do both commands at the same time (killall unity-settings-daemon &&
unity-settings-daemon --debug), one out of every 10 times I can restart before it autorestarts, but this isn't reliable. There must be some other configuration file in which to disable autorestart that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/unity-settings-daemon.conf`

> description "The Unity Settings Daemon" author "Dimitri John Ledkov
>   "
>
> start on started dbus and starting gnome-session INSTANCE!=GNOME stop
>   on stopping gnome-session
>
> respawn
>
> exec /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon

I' d comment out the `respawn` line.